# How to use TensorflowInferenceInterface in an Android App

Tags: java, android, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am using a trained model (frozen graph) in my Android app that utilises Tensorflow's premade estimator iris example as shown in this link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/iris.py

I have modified iris.py to suit with my needs and added some statements to freeze the graph so that I have a .pb file to be put into my Android app's assets folder.

To use Tensorflow in my Android app, I have added the following line into my build.gradle (Module: app) file (the last statement in the dependencies block).

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+'
}
```

With my frozen graph in place, I was testing out if Tensorflow is working my app by executing these statements:

```
    //testing tensorflow feature
    TensorFlowInferenceInterface tfInterface = new 
    TensorFlowInferenceInterface(
            getAssets(), "estimator_frozen_graph.pb");
    Graph graph = tfInterface.graph();
    Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this, "Tensorflow Graph Init Success", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int[] inputValues = {1, 1, 121, 800, 300};
    long rowDim = 1;
    long columnDim = 5;

    tfInterface.feed("dnn/input_from_feature_columns/input_layer/concat:0",
            inputValues, rowDim, columnDim);
    String[] outputNames = {"dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0"};
    boolean logstats = false;
    tfInterface.run(outputNames, logstats);
    float[] outputs = new float[6];
    tfInterface.fetch("dnn/logits/BiasAdd:0", outputs);
    for(int i = 0; i<= outputs.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(outputs[i]);
    }
```

When the program reaches the line:

```
tfInterface.run(outputNames, logstats);
```

The following Error information appeared in Android Studio's logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Iterator' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

[[Node: Iterator = Iterator[container="", output_shapes=[[?], [?], [?], [?], [?], [?]], output_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], shared_name=""]()]]
    at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
```

I have been searching for similar questions and problems but I cannot seem to find a viable solution to this problem.

Please tell me if I need to add any information to ease the process of getting assistance here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my own problem. Turns out I have not understood the concept of freezing the model properly with Tensorflow.
The short answer to this question is:

1. Follow the appropriate steps to freeze the graph generated by the model (In this case, a DNN classifier) by utilising freezeGraph.py.
2. Include the frozen protobuf file in the Android project "assets" folder.
3. Read the guide on the implementation of Tensorflow in an Android App here:
   http://aqibsaeed.github.io/2017-05-02-deploying-tensorflow-model-andorid-device-human-activity-recognition/